# isset($_POST) is correct usage or not?

Tags: php, post

The problem I'm facing is quite common I suppose but I didn't see a single thread in internet.

If I use `isset($_POST)`,

1. Will it always return `true`?
2. Does the response depend on the version of PHP I use?
3. Is `$_POST` is a variable? (it's a super global 'variable' after all). Because in php.net documentation, it is mentioned

**`isset()` only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will it always return true?

Yes, even if the page was opened using `GET` method or nothing was `POST`ed.

> Does the response depend on the version of PHP I use?

No it does not (not sure about very old versions of PHP).

> Is $_POST is a variable?

Yes

> isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error.

This is explicitly mentioned in the manual so that people do not try to do *cheaky* stuff. These won't work for example:

```
function getVarName() { return '_POST'; }
isset(getVarName());
isset('$_POST');
```

Now, why would you want to check if `$_POST` is set. Perhaps want to check if a certain variable (e.g. email) was posted, in that case you need to check:

```
isset($_POST["email"])
```

Comment: Well, While coding I forgot to add $_POST['registrationid']. It is working fine in my local machine. So I didnt bother to correct it. But when I deployed this in actual server it is giving error. I could do this correction but I dont have credentials now to deploy it in server. So I thought it is better to know more before asking the client to upload code again. :) Thanks for the replies.

Comment: But If I use GET method for the page, then $_POST is not set. I verified it.

Answer (score 1):

`isset($_POST);` will always return true. If you want to check if it contains something use `empty($_POST);`

> Does the response depend on the version of PHP I use?

No

> Is $_POST is a variable ?

Yes

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using one of the following:

```
if($_POST){

}
if(!empty($_POST)){

}
```

1, Will it always return true?

> isset($_POST) will always return true. If $_POST is empty it will return false.

2, Does the response depend on the version of PHP I use?

> I'm not sure about versions below 4.* but the response has always been the same.

3, Is $_POST is a variable?

> Yes, it is considered a superglobal like: $GLOBALS, $_SESSION, $_POST, $_GET

Comment: The `is_array` one will always evaluate to true. `$_POST` is set even if there is no POST-data and an empty array will still pass the `is_array` check.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you posted any data `$_POST` will always be set as an array. What you are probably looking for is the `empty()` method to see if any data was actually posted, like:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // POST data was set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Will it always return true?

Yes it would always be true

- Does the response depend on the version of PHP I use?

No tested on [PHP 4.3.0 - 5.4.10](http://3v4l.org/saPAf)

- Is `$_POST` is a variable?

Definitely Yes

Better way to validate `$_POST` is to use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
Isset()
```

return true only if it contains some value (it can be Zero 0).
If it doesn't have any value then it returns false.
If you want to prevent from  (0) use

```
if(isset($_POST) && $_POST)
```

This will be true if only it has non-zero value

```
$_POST is global array

Response doesn't depend upon the version of PHP
```